# Autograph in TensorFlow 1.15 gives TypeError in conditional statement with value assignment in one branch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conditional-statements

**System information**

- Custom code: Yes
- OS Platform: Windows 10 PC
- TensorFlow version: 1.15.0
- Python version: 3.6

**Current behavior**

If a constant value is assigned to variable in one branch of conditional statement, then data type of that value is inferred for the variable, which need not align with the intended data type of the variable leading to TypeError. The issue is that one is expected to know about any assignment in python source code (and its type) before using autograph to create the graph and assign placeholder dtype, which is not always practical. See example minimal code below.

**Code to reproduce the issue**

Modification of square_if_positive method from TensorFlow documentation

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import autograph as ag

#minimal code for method to demonstrate issue
def foo(x):
    if x > 0:
        y = x * x
    else:
        y = 0.0
    return y

#graph construction
mdl = tf.Graph()
with mdl.as_default():
    converted_foo = ag.to_graph(foo)
    print(ag.to_code(foo))
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.double, name='x')
    y = converted_foo(x)
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: "y" has dtype float64 in the TRUE branch, but dtype=float32 in the FALSE branch. TensorFlow control flow requires that they are the same.
```

See detailed traceback below.

How can we modify code or autograph behavior for the code to work successfully?

One (undesirable) workaround is to define `x` as:
`x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='x')`

However, this assignment will now fail to work, if `foo` was:

```
#minimal code for method to demonstrate issue
def foo(x):
    if x > 0:
        y = x * x
    else:
        y = 0
    return y
```

and new error is:

```
TypeError: "y" has dtype float32 in the TRUE branch, but dtype=int32 in the FALSE branch. TensorFlow control flow requires that they are the same.
```

Is there a more suitable workaround?

**Other info / logs**
Error log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-9455269f4d6f> in <module>
     16     print(ag.to_code(foo))
     17     x = tf.placeholder(tf.double, name='x')
---> 18     y = converted_foo(x)

C:\Users\212613~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3yjohro5.py in tf__foo(x)
     23           return y
     24         cond = x > 0
---> 25         y = ag__.if_stmt(cond, if_true, if_false, get_state, set_state, ('y',), ())
     26         do_return = True
     27         retval_ = foo_scope.mark_return_value(y)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\kchain\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\operators\control_flow.py in if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state, basic_symbol_names, composite_symbol_names)
    891   if tensors.is_dense_tensor(cond):
    892     return tf_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state,
--> 893                       basic_symbol_names, composite_symbol_names)
    894   else:
    895     return _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\kchain\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\operators\control_flow.py in tf_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state, basic_symbol_names, composite_symbol_names)
    929 
    930   final_vars, final_state = control_flow_ops.cond(cond, error_checking_body,
--> 931                                                   error_checking_orelse)
    932 
    933   set_state(final_state)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\kchain\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    505                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    506                 instructions)
--> 507       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    508 
    509     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\kchain\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, strict, name, fn1, fn2)
   1233     try:
   1234       context_f.Enter()
-> 1235       orig_res_f, res_f = context_f.BuildCondBranch(false_fn)
   1236       if orig_res_f is None:
   1237         raise ValueError("false_fn must have a return value.")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\kchain\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in BuildCondBranch(self, fn)
   1059     """Add the subgraph defined by fn() to the graph."""
   1060     pre_summaries = ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys._SUMMARY_COLLECTION)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 1061     original_result = fn()
   1062     post_summaries = ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys._SUMMARY_COLLECTION)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1063     if len(post_summaries) > len(pre_summaries):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\kchain\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\operators\control_flow.py in error_checking_orelse()
    925     if result[body_branch] is not None:
    926       _verify_tf_cond_vars(result[body_branch], result[orelse_branch],
--> 927                            basic_symbol_names, composite_symbol_names)
    928     return result[orelse_branch]
    929 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\kchain\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\operators\control_flow.py in _verify_tf_cond_vars(body_outputs, orelse_outputs, basic_symbol_names, composite_symbol_names)
    259 
    260     nest.map_structure(
--> 261         functools.partial(_check_same_type, name), body_output, orelse_output)
    262 
    263 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\kchain\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    534 
    535   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 536       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    537       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    538 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\kchain\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    534 
    535   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 536       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    537       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    538 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\kchain\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\operators\control_flow.py in _check_same_type(name, body_output_var, orelse_output_var)
    256             ' branch. TensorFlow control flow requires that they are the'
    257             ' same.'.format(name, body_output_var.dtype.name,
--> 258                             orelse_output_var.dtype.name))
    259 
    260     nest.map_structure(

TypeError: "y" has dtype float64 in the TRUE branch, but dtype=float32 in the FALSE branch. TensorFlow control flow requires that they are the same.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following line,

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.double, name='x')
```

Simply change it to,

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='x')
```

Here `double` is `float64` so your function produces inconsistent data types. If `x > 0` you get `float64` and else you get `float32` (that's TF default float type).

```
if x > 0.0:
        y = x * x
    else:
        y = 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Appreciate it! As identified in my question, initializing x as placeholder of type tf.float32 is a known workaround and modifying the script (if...else block) is not desirable, as that code can come from an arbitrary service. Is there a better way?